# Is it possible to bring a GUID from SQL Server in PostgreSQL using a Foreign Table?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am trying to pull in data from a table in SQL Server into PostgreSQL using a Foreign Table. Example:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE test
   (testguid text ,
    name text )
   SERVER test_server
   OPTIONS (schema_name 'dbo', table_name 'test');
```

My problem is that the first field `testguid` is a GUID data type in SQL Server. Something like ca902d1e-1082-e711-80bf-005056bdd6cd. This came into PostgreSQL as blank. The other non GUID fields are coming correctly.

Does anybody have a solution for doing this?

Comment: I'm not a postgresql expert by any means, but it might be because a guid is considered binary, and passing binary objects around sometimes behave... badly. You might try casting it to a varchar first then cast it back once it's moved over.

Comment: Did you try `uuid` as the data type for `testguid` instead of `text`?

Comment: My solution for now is to create a view in SQL Server casting the GUID to a varchar and then pulling it into PostgreSQL as a foriegn table. This works, not ideal but works.